# Cannot Facebook "Like" with Graph API's /OBJECT_ID/likes

Tags: android, facebook

I'd like to implement a like button in my Android app. The Graph API doc sais publishing likes can be done with **/OBJECT_ID/likes**.

> **/OBJECT_ID/likes**
>
> Like the given object (if it has a
> /likes connection)

However if i implement this:

```
Bundle par = new Bundle(); 
par.putString("access_token", ACCESS_TOKEN);
facebook.request(APP_ID + "/likes", par, "POST");
```

it just does nothing but returns an empty (data content) JSON array. (publish_stream permission is given.)

APP_ID is my app's FB id, and i guess it'd be the OBJECT_ID so i don't understand.
How can i implement then a Like button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot force users to like your application or your fan page (due to spamming reasons). The only way you can get them to like your page/app is embedding the like fbml code or iframe in a web view.  That documentation is in place to like a friends wall post or comment or photo, as those are the types of items you can like for a user, in case for example you were writing a Facebook client. If that is what you are trying to do, don't send the app_id as you are doing, but send the post id of the users post.

Comment: thanks!
this is crazy.. i guess if somebody really wants to "spam" like that she could make a script to do that with webview too... 
i've inegrated my apps wall into the app but "like" is needed for the user to be able to post on it. 
Anyway i made it work with webview and a like button.

Comment: As user still clicks on something to like that page, you could simply use facebook native app like this: Intent likeFB = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/YOUR_FB_PAGE_ID"));